# How to display composite signal from my video capture card?

Tags: video

I bought an AverMedia DVD EZMaker Gold capture card:

[image]

The card came with a drivers CD and another Cyberlink CD none of which contain an utility for viewing the captured [composite video signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video)?!

How am I supposed to view the incoming signal? (The video signal is coming from my Wii console.) I tried VLC player but to no avail (it just displays a black screen).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dscaler](http://deinterlace.sourceforge.net/):

> **What is DScaler?**
>
> The DScaler project is an ongoing attempt to get the best video
>   quality possible from a Windows PC. At the moment the project has two
>   main strands.
>
> - [TV Viewing Application (DScaler 4)](http://deinterlace.sourceforge.net/dscaler4.htm)
> - [Media decoders (DScaler 5)](http://deinterlace.sourceforge.net/dscaler5.htm)